# MS Paint memory usage

Tags: memory, images, microsoft-paint

Why my machine uses 2.5Gb of RAM to open 250Mb bmp file using MS Paint?

I was basically using some dense jpeg files to combine it into one large file, using MS Paint. The file as saved on the drive is roughly 250MB. But when it was loaded into Paint, it took 2.5Gb of RAM. Now, when it is saved on the drive, I can open it in "preview" and it "eats" 1Gb of RAM. Re-opening it in Paint is impossible. So, it has to be one-time deal. But I can't build file large enough file for me because it just eats all memory on my Win7 Pro VM with 5.xxx Gb of RAM. Is this just the way paint parses image parts?

Comment: Try Paint.net. But it will still consume about 1GB of RAM to open your 250MB image. Irfanview will only consume 250MB but it might not be able to do what you need. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @SpiderPig the question really is, why Paint eats up 2.5G for 250M bitmap?

Comment: Because Paint was badly designed.

Comment: btw. If you can find a computer with winxp on it, copy mspaint.exe from there over to your PC. It will be able to open your 250 MB bmp just fine and needs less than 1 GB of RAM for it. So somehow Microsoft managed to make Paint even more crappy over time.

Comment: analyze [memory usage grow with WPR/WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks#time=16m57s). For Windows 7 use the [v1511 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771) to install the Windows Performance Toolkit.

Comment: @SpiderPig Thank you. This is already something! It just drove me crazy to understand why opening a file takes 10x memory this file takes on disk

Answer (score 2):

JPGs are compressed, they will be decompressed (converted to a raw bitmap (BMP)) during editing.

The [typical ratio for JPG compression is 10:1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).  So when decompressed, your 250MB JPG could climb to ~2.5GB in size.

Try using [a more robust image editor](https://www.gimp.org/).